# How to edit and enlarge the font in a PDF document?

Tags: pdf, fonts, editing

I have a 6" Kindle. I often read technical PDF files, but the problem is that they don't get converted very well to Kindle's native format (for example, code blocks get messed up, etc).  When looking at the PDF page, it's too small to read easily.  I can rotate the screen to a horizontal position in order to see it better, but my page gets divided.

Some documents would be easy to read in vertical position if I had the chance to enlarge the font size in an external PDf editor.

**Is there a way to change the font size in a PDF file?**

Comment: Actually, this one has a specific question about enlarging font size in a pdf. I reworked the question, to focus on that, instead of closing as a duplicate.

Comment: Ok, voting to reopen now, so.

Comment: i agree with @Gnoupi, this isn't the same question.  reopening.  for reference, the related question is here: http://superuser.com/questions/80456/how-to-enlarge-a-pdf-document-on-kindle

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to do this.

In a PDF file, words are either represented as graphics (worst case), or as text with coordinates... *per word* (and sometimes even per character). If you only patch the style information in order to resize the characters, the word positions will not match any more: you will just get larger, but overlapping text.

So, it's not about editing a PDF, but about *importing PDF content*, doing some edits (possibly with re-hyphenating, re-wrapping texts and creating new page breaks) and *writing a new PDF file*.

With text-only PDFs, you could try to use Calibre (and maybe Sigil for some regexp postprocessing), or even try out the import functions some word processors offer nowadays.  But with technical PDFs containing tables, code blocks, or engineering drawings, you will quite fast meet the limits of these tools.

Maybe an 8" ebook reader would be the easiest solution to your problem.